Boy finds giant jumping bean
I encountered this children's story before 1995, probably in the '80s. I remember it being in a paperback book.
The main character was a young boy. I think he was on holiday. The place he was staying had a lot of Mexican jumping beans, and an adult - probably his father - explained about the insects that live inside them and their life-cycle.  Nearby was a large rocky hill or mountain that was shaped like a jumping bean and called something appropriate like "bean rock" or "bean hill".
Towards the end of the story, the rock turned out to be an enormous jumping bean: it jumped end-over-end out of its place and hopped/rolled away. I think it was either implied or stated that a giant moth emerged from it and flew away, but I don't remember if they saw the moth or found the now-hollow rock.
